# List file in macos with formatted datetime (equivalent to find -printf in linux)

Tags: bash, macos

I want to list all files that ends extension (.xyz) with corresponding datetime(created/updated).

I have this on linux:

```
find ~/path/to/files -name "*.xyz" -type f -printf '%TF_%TT %p\n'

Result:
03-03-2020_01:01:01 /path/to/files/file1.xyz
03-03-2020_01:01:02 /path/to/files/file2.xyz
```

However, printf is not supported in macOs. Any other way to achieve this feat without installing any 3rd party?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, using `stat` command with `find` and `awk` here.. Since I don't have mac so couldn't test on it.

```
find -type f -iname "*.xyz" -exec stat {} \+ |
awk -F'[ .]' '/File:/{match($0,/\/[^\047]*/);file=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1);next} /Modify:/{print $2,$3,file;file=""}'
```

***Explanation:***

- Running `find` command on all files which have extension `xyz`.
- Running `stat` command with `exec` to run `stat` command on all files which have come as result with `find` command.
- Now passing `find` command's output to `awk` command as an Input.
- Parsing data and printing only modify timings of files along with their names as per OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX you may use this `find + stat + date` command in `bash`:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
    date -r $(stat -f '%m' "$f") '+%d-%m-%Y_%T'$'\t'"$f"
done < <(find ~/path/to/files  -type f -name '*.xyz' -print0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that command works fine on Linux and not on MacOS is because Apple bundles the BSD variant of the `find` program. Your options are to either continue suffering with all of the weird (and in some cases, very outdated) BSD tools<sup>1</sup>, or fix the problem at the source. If you are content to not change things and want to keep things the way they are, go with one of the other answers; this answer is how you fix this issue permanently.

I know you stipulated no 3rd party, but trust me (a random person on the internet), this will make your life much easier. Do yourself a big favor: if you haven't already, go install homebrew.

Once it's installed, use it to install just a few things:

```
brew install bash colordiff cowsay gcc gdb glib gmp gnu-getopt gnu-sed gnu-tar gnu-time gnu-which gnupg gnutls grep lynx netcat pcre2 perl
readline vim wget xz coreutils findutils binutils
```

They should all be installed as symlinks from `/usr/local/Cellar/[...]` to `/usr/local/bin` (or `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/[...]` to `/opt/homebrew/bin` on Apple Silicon systems) but some are installed with a `g` prefix. If that is not what you want, just rename the links without the `g`, for example:

```
x86 systems: mv /usr/local/bin/gfind /usr/local/bin/find
Apple Silicon systems: mv /opt/homebrew/bin/gfind /opt/homebrew/bin/find
```

Last, update the your profile to put homebrew's `bin` directory first on your `PATH`:

```
x86 systems: echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> $HOME/.bash_profile
Apple Silicon systems: 'export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH' >> $HOME/.bash_profile
```

Now find (and many other tools) will work as expected.

---

<sup>1</sup>Explanation: Apple ships macOS with BSD versions of a lot of the CLI tools. Some tools don't have a version with a BSD-style license; in that case, they find a version licensed under GPLv2 (like bash 3.x from 2007, which is probably what you're using if it's never been intentionally updated). They apparently are concerned with the "infectious" nature of GPLv3. Doing what I suggested will leave you with the nice modern GNU versions of the CLI tools and your command line will be a lot more like what you're used to on Linux.

Comment: `cowsay` is the most important.